# How redirect in onSecurityInteractiveLogin method in LoginListener - Symfony2

Tags: redirect, symfony, listener, handler

We want to redirect to a path or another after login. Also we need to pass de language in this path.

We have a Login Listener as a service to check this. Our problem is to do the redirect accion.
Code:

```
<service id="acme.login_listener" class="acme\DemoBundle\Listener\LoginListener">
   <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" method="onSecurityInteractiveLogin" priority="-1" />
   <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="filter.response" method="onKernelResponse" />            
   <argument type="service" id="service_container" />  
   <argument type="service" id="router" />          
</service>
```

The listener code:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginListener 
{
    protected $container;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, Router $router)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {                
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $username = $token->getUsername();

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

        $user = $em->getRepository('acmeDemoBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);


        $locale = strtolower($user->getUsuari()->getIdioma()->getCodi6391());
        $locale = 'ca';  //force locale test

        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->setLocale($locale);          
        $session->set('idioma', $locale);    
        $session->set('_locale', $locale); 
        $session->set('locale', $locale);

        $url = $this->router->generate('onePath', array('_locale' => $locale));

        //$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
        //$event->stopPropagation();
        //echo $url;exit;

        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);            
        return $response;  
...
```

Our problem is to do the redirect to the wished path in onSecurityInteractiveLogin function.

We tried to do the $event->setResponse but it doesn't work. This $event var doesn't have this method.

Any idea?
Thanks for your help.

---

Edited: second option (Jan 27, 2012)

Following: http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/

I tried to use Handlers. I configured the services.xml:

```
<service id="company.login_success_handler" class="project\demoBundle\Handler\LoginSucessHandler">
    <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="project" />
    <argument type="service" id="logger" /> 
    <argument type="service" id="router" />          
</service>
```

ON security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            success_handler: company.login_success_handler
            use_forward: false
```

And in Symfony/src/project/demoBundle/Handler/loginSuccessHandler.php

```
<?php 

namespace project\demoBundle\Handler; 

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext; 

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse; 
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router; 

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface 
{ 

  protected $router; 
  protected $security; 

  public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security) 
  { 
    $this->router = $router; 
    $this->security = $security; 
    echo "hello world";exit;
  } 

  public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) 
  { 

    echo "hello world 2";exit;
    if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) 
    { 
      $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('category_index'));       
    } 
    elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) 
    { 
      $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('category_index')); 
    }  
    elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) 
    { 
      // redirect the user to where they were before the login process begun. 
      $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer'); 

      $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url); 
    } 

    return $response; 
  } 

}
```

But if I execute the web app, it doesn't into at this function and doesn't show "Hello world".

Do you know what I'm doing bad?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the UrlGeneratorInterface used in FOSUserBundle

[FosUserBundle Hooking into controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
...

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}
...
...

$url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a handler instead of an event listener if you need to change the response. More information here: http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/

Comment: Hello TheOnly92, thanks for your answer.
I tried to use handler in my code but it doesn't works. I think that I forgot something maybe.
When I make login the app doesn't into to onAuthenticationSucess.
I config services.XML and security.yml how the example shows

Comment: I have tried again and it works very well. The link sent by @theonly92 is the answer for our purposes. Thanks!

Comment: That link appears to be broken now.